# Auto answer command in BASH For loop

Tags: shell, io-redirection

I am testing tls renegotiation using this "for" loop and need to auto-answer with "R" for each iteration, I expected one of these permutations to work, neither of these is working, grateful for any suggestions

```
for ((i=0;i<10;i++)) 
do
"R" > echo `openssl s_client -connect 192.168.1.1:443`
done

for ((i=0;i<10;i++)) 
do
echo `openssl s_client -connect 192.168.1.1:443` < "R"
done
```

Comment: Why `echo`? See [this](https://superuser.com/q/1352850/432690).

Comment: `<` and `>` redirect from and to files, you need a pipe instead to redirect from one command to another. See also: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput

Answer (score 0):

First will not work because bash expect `R` to be command

Seconds will work if you send this `R` to the command (not to the `echo`):

```
openssl s_client -connect 192.168.1.1:443 <<< "R"
```

This form `<` will not work because it expect on the right side to be file.

Comment: You'll probably need `(echo R; sleep 1) | openssl s_client -connect host:port` to leave enough time for that `R` to complete a renegotiation.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, never tested, probably :)

Comment: Hey Romeo!  thanks!  "<<< "R" worked!   Thanks also to Stephane, that structure gave me some ideas, great appreciate your help!